# how to handle CannotCreateTransactionException when connecting with database in spring mvc

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

In my application i want to handle CannotCreateTransactionException, sql exceptions and other exceptions. i"m new to spring mvc and hibernate. If any thing is not in the best way then please let me know so that i can change my code.

mehtod in my controller is like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/validatingmobilenumber",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody() 
    public String validateMobileNumber(@RequestParam("mobilenumber") String mobilenumber)
    {
        try
        {
            User userDetails=userServices.getUserByPhoneNumber(mobilenumber);
            if(userDetails.getUserID()!=0)
            {               
                return "mobilenumber already exists";
            }
            else
                return "new mobilenumber";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Unable to connect to DB";//if any type of exception occurred this is going to returned.
    }
```

my service like this

```
@Service("userServices")
public class UserServicesImpl implements UserServices {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public User getUserByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {

        return userDao.getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

My dao

```
@Transactional
@Repository("UserDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public User getUserByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {

        User userDetails=new User();
        User userDetails1=new User();

        try
        {
            if((userDetails1=(User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where phoneNumber=:phoneNumber")
                .setParameter("phoneNumber", phoneNumber).uniqueResult())!= null)
            {

                return userDetails1;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            userDetails.setUserID(0);

        }

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which class and method is throwing the exception?  Is your service class autowired in your controller?  Can you verify you are establishing a database connection when running your application?

Comment: Ya. my app is running fine if db properties are correct.

Comment: if db properties are wrong then I want to return a string like 'Unable to connect to db'

Comment: Have you tried changing your db properties so that they are incorrect and then adding `try {} catch (e){}` to the appropriate methods?  You can also add error handling to your web.xml file to intercept specific errors and redirect to pages.

Comment: Actually these are web services. So I have to return a string that will describe the problem to the users(eg. android app)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old post. Hope I will help others.

What is the problem here ? You have the issue and have the solution also!

In Ajax calls, you will do exactly like what you do now and you will handle the response in your jsp page and, in case of none Ajax calls, you will need to return the page name as string and to attach the error you want in the model object like `model.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);`

Comment: I want to know is there any easy way (Best way) to handle above scenario?

Comment: I described what I know. Don't know if there is more easier way or not.